# E: Unable to locate package geonode: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: geonode

I am trying to follow quick installation guide for GeoNode on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
https://docs.geonode.org/en/2.8/tutorials/install_and_admin/quick_install.html

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geonode/stable
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install geonode

However, when I try to run last line, it shows me error:
E: Unable to locate package geonode

If you look at the screenshot: there are already errors while adding repository, such as "E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file." and others...

What could be the solution?

[image: sudo add-apt-repository]

Answer (score 1):

There is simply no way to install Geonode using the ppa way as there are no Geonode packages available for this Ubuntu release ("Focal Fossa"). When you go to [https://launchpad.net/~geonode/+archive/ubuntu/testing](https://launchpad.net/%7Egeonode/+archive/ubuntu/testing), you get the following list and 20.04 is not included.

[image]

You should use alternate solutions e.g like Docker (https://docs.geonode.org/en/2.8/tutorials/install_and_admin/running_docker/index.html) or adapt [Development install recipe](https://docs.geonode.org/en/2.8/tutorials/install_and_admin/quick_install.html#ubuntu-for-development) to install Geonode at the moment